# Address array index without knowing size JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I am trying to address an array i.e.

```
var arrayName = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'etc.'];
return arrayName[n].length;
```

returns 5, 5, 4

Basically, I want to return the length of every index without knowing how many items there are.  I am sure this is way easier than I am thinking but I am in a hole and can't think straight.

thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You always can find the length of an array by examining its `.length` property.

Comment: "length of every index" == length of each element in array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to generate a new array based on existing array element.

```js
var arrayName = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'etc.'];

console.log(
  arrayName.map(function(s) {
    return s.length;
  })
);
```

---

**UPDATE :** For getting the largest string use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

```js
function findLongestWord(str) {
  return str.split(' ').reduce(function(p, n) {
    return p.length >= n.length ? p : n;
  });
}

console.log(findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"));
```

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't give complete information.  what I actually have is...

function findLongestWord(str) {
  var longest = str.split(' ');
      
}

findLongestWord("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog");

Comment: You are the bomb.com

Answer (score 0):

you can use forEach in vanilla JavaScript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

```js
var arrayName = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'etc.'];
arrayName.forEach(function(elem){
  console.log(elem.length)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getLengths() {
  var arrayName = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'etc.'];
  return arrayName.map(function (name) {return name.length});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayName = ['lorem', 'ipsum', 'etc.'];
var lengthofElements=[];

function showLength(arr){
    for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        lengthofElements.push(arr[i].length);
    }
    return lengthofElements;
}

console.log(showLength(arrayName).toString());
```

Hope you wanted this. it shows 5,5,4 works with any array.

Comment: this is a basic approach suitable for learner. map is better and more elegant option.